# Number of integral roots?

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

The number of integral roots of the equation

> $x^8-24x^7-18x^5+39x^2+1155=0$

I tried to figure out by considering the changes in signs which tell us that there are atmost $2$ positive real roots and no negative real root.

But that does not help out with integer roots.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: Descartes rule gives you only the possibility of zero or two positive real roots, not $3$. Now try for small positive factors of $1155$, as the $x^8$ term dominates very fast.

Comment: If $x_1,\ldots,x_8$ the roots of equation $x^8-24x^7-18x^5+39x^2+1155=0$ then 
$$
x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3\cdot x_4\cdot x_5\cdot x_6\cdot x_7\cdot x_8=1155=3\cdot 5\cdot7\cdot 11
$$

Comment: Yeah all that helped, i got it thnx, bt still its a hectic work to put values in $x^8-24x^7........$ and solve the polynomial.

Comment: @Displayname No, it changes twice. Once from positive to negative, then again back to positive.

Comment: *two* changes.  Rational roots will all be factors try them 1155 = 1.3.5.7.11.  Try them.  Can't be 3 because x^8+....+39x^2 must be divisible by 3^3 but 1155 is only divisible by 3.  Can't be 5 because every term would end in 5 so the polynomial would end in 5.  Not 1 because .... well, c'mon.  Can't be 11. because 1 - 4 - 8 +9 +5 doesn't equal 0.  So that leaves 7..

Comment: 7: seven is rel prime to 10 so last digit of 7^4 is 1 so last digits are 1 - 4*3 - 8*9 + 9*9 +5 = 7 which is not 0 so not 7.  No integer roots.  (I hope-- this is exactly the type of situation where I make a careless error and make a fool of myself.)

Comment: Oops.  Those last two comments were silly because I didn't consider combinations of primes.... oh, well.  But the eight does dominate.  I doubt you'll have to try any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another way. Rather simple and old school.
Take the 1155 to the other side. (1155=3.5.7.11)
Also take x^2 common from the expression.
x^2 is not a factor of any of the primes of the 1155 (3.5.7.11)
Hence no integral roots.

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ is an integer root of $x^8-24x^7-18x^5+39x^2+1155$ then $a$ must be a factor of $1155=3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11$ so there are $(1+1)(1+1)(1+1)(1+1)=16$ positive possible factors and a way to see that any of them is a root would be division by $(x-a)$ for possible $a$.

But is much better to remark that criterium of Eisenstein apply with the prime $3$ so the given polynomial is irreducible and there are not root even rational.

Comment: Believe it or not, I was not familiar with Eisenstein criterium.  Perhaps you can include a description of what it is and how it applies.  (BtW as the leading coefficient is one all possible rational roots would be integers.)

Comment: It is the most popular of the criteriums: If in $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$, a prime $p$ divides  all of the coefficients $a_{n-1},...,a_0$ but $p^2$ does not divides $a_0$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible (over $\mathbb Q$)

Comment: I meant maybe you should put it in your answer.  It's a one and a half line complete and total answer to the question.  One can't do much better than that.

Answer (score 0):

In my view the easiest approach is to use even-odd parity. 
If $a$ is an odd number we would have 3 odd integers and 2 even integers which can never result in 0 ( an even integer ).
 Similarly, if we say that $a$ is an even integer then only constant term is an odd term which means we can't get a 0 again.